# Team League North America

Tags: team

In Europe, each country organizes a team league, which are known highly competitive like Bundesliga in Germany or Top 12 in France as an example.

Is there similar competition in North America (Canada, US) inside the states?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a chess league in the US, but it does not have the sponsorship you see in Europe. Check the [USCF](http://www.uschess.org) website, and this more specific site http://uschessleague.com/

Comment: What team league does the USCF run? The closest thing the USCF has is the amateur team tournaments. We don't have anything like the team leagues in Europe unfortunately.

Comment: US Chess League I believe is defunct, and replaced by the Pro Chess League on chess.com.

Comment: Coolest thing I've seen today  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Professional_Rapid_Online_Chess_League